# How do I open Visual Studio in "Open Web Site Mode" programmatically with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, envdte

I am developed a Win Forms application with C#.
The user browses for .NET Projects on his local drive. He/she selects the .NET Projects to open in Web Site Mode.

**Functionality** (to develop in C#)**:**
Is there a possibility, in C# code, to allow the user to open Projects as **Web Site Projects** in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'd try is just passing a folder path to devenv and see what happens.

Looking at this page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sf6kk3.aspx) it looks like you can use the /Command switch when you launch devenv.exe. Then going into Visual Studio (Tools > Options > Keyboard) I see there's a `File.OpenWebSite` command. I haven't tried this, but putting those things together I'm assuming you could do something like:

```
devenv.exe /command "File.OpenWebSite" [path]
```

The `[path]` part is going to be the big question mark. The `File.OpenWebSite` command might just open the dialog in Visual Studio.

You could also take a look at automating the IDE itself, as this post discusses. It's for VS2005 but might still work for newer versions.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c8e5b16-b616-4de4-9744-6594be4f474c/automating-opening-of-a-website-in-vs2005?forum=vsx

```
System.Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0", true);
DTE dte = (DTE)System.Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);

VsWebSite.VSWebPackage webPkg = (VsWebSite.VSWebPackage)dte.GetObject("WebPackage");
webPkg.OpenWebSite(path, VsWebSite.OpenWebsiteOptions.OpenWebsiteOption_None, false);
```

Comment: if you complete the declaration of DTE, I can accept this as the answer.